# Laravel query `whereIn` get 1 data from each array

Tags: database, laravel-4

I have a query where I would like to get 1 data from each category, like this, in Laravel 4:

`DB::table('my_table')->whereIn('cat', array('cat1', 'cat2', 'cat3'))->take(1)->orderBy('date', 'desc')->get()`

Problem is that this won't produce what I want, It retrieves only 1 data from `cat1` (and ignore `cat2` and `cat3` ), even if I removed `take`, it will retrieve 2 or more data from `cat1`.

What I want is retrieve only 1 data from each `cat`, how to do this in Laravel?

**SOLUTION**

Solved my problem using something like this

```
$list = array('cat1', 'cat2', 'cat3');

DB::table('news')->whereIn('cat', $list)->take(count($list))->groupBy('cat')->orderBy('date', 'desc')->get();
```

Comment: Why do you need the `take()` at all? If you have more than one news with the same cat, the `groupBy` or a `distinct()` will avoid duplicates.

Comment: I forgot about `distinct()` but it works anyway, thanks for the answer, I upvoted

Comment: or you can do with first(); method. that same way. :)

Comment: @antoniputra the data collected by first() on a whereIn() can't be filtred as a collection, i had this issue and i think i'm gonna use take(count($table)) too